# docker config mongodb shard cluster failed

Tags: mongodb, docker

Here i want to configure a shard cluster for mongodb in docker environment, everything ok except mongos container always can not start properly. using `docker ps -a --no-trunc` to check its ful command and show like below.
[image]

and my configsvr and shardsvr are both ok except `mongos` server can not start. Maybe something error in my docker startup args. And here is my order:
`docker run -d -p 22001:20001 --name mongos_container1 6cd805d051d3 --configdb crs/192.168.0.137:21001,192.168.0.137:21002 --port 20001` . And i don't think it can do with docker images but really don't know why? hope someone can take me out.

## update:

this is my `mongod` dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.docker-cn.com/library/centos

# maintained by Crabime
MAINTAINER songsx@gooalgene.com

# create workspace for docker
RUN mkdir -p /home/software
WORKDIR /home/software
RUN yum install -y unzip zip

# export some port in host
EXPOSE 20001
EXPOSE 22

ADD mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.6.3.tgz /usr/local
# docker will unzip zip file automatically
RUN mv /usr/local/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.6.3 /usr/local/mongodb-3.6.3
# reflection files from host to docker
# ADD mongodb/ /usr/local/mongodb-3.6.3/conf
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mongodb-3.6.3

ENV MONGO_HOME /usr/local/mongodb-3.6.3
ENV PATH="/usr/local/mongodb-3.6.3/bin:${PATH}"

# chech such file located inside workdir?
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
ENTRYPOINT mongod
```

and this is my `mongos` dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/mongo:v1.5
ENTRYPOINT mongos
```

Comment: What is the `CMD` in mongos image's Dockerfile?

Comment: I have already update my dockerfile for mongod and mongos